# Are carbohydrates an essential component of human diet?

Tags: metabolism, diet, carbohydrates

Are people able to satisfy all the needs of a healthy diet without consuming carbohydrates?

My question includes the assumption that a person has no health condition that would prevent them from meeting their caloric needs with only fat and protein.

I'm also not asking about the practicality of eliminating all carbohydrates.  If a person could consume no carbohydrates whatsoever, this other question would clearly matter a lot, but I'm not asking it.

If there are essential dietary components that happen to be carbohydrates, but are not converted into glucose, I'll say up front that it wouldn't satisfy what I"m asking.  However, it would be interesting footnote on an otherwise correct answer.

Comment: While it's possible to live that way for some period of time, your body will be dying of stress. Your liver and kidneys will be first to fail. Your brain and muscles will struggle as well. Regarding your last paragraph, dietary fibers (comprised of different carbohydrates) are essential to maintain healthy digestive system and microflora, and the later has a tremendous impact on your immunity.

Comment: @Christiaan it won't. Beta-exidation of fats produces acetyl-CoA that fuels the citric acid cycle when there are no sugar resources left.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, thats interesting. Will look into that, thanks.

Comment: @Christiaan sorry for the typo, it was supposed to be "beta-oxidation".

Comment: http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/75/5/951.2.long Check this out.

Comment: @243 interesting article from Journal of Nutrition - I've never though of carbs as being essential - given that fatty acids can supply power via beta-oxidation and all the amino acids are either ketogenic, glucogenic, or both - and thus can supply the TCA cycle via anapleurotic reactions. Sounds like the Inuit populations with almost no carb intake do just fine - suggesting that dietary carbohydrates are not required for life - very interesting

Comment: I've heard (link missing) that our brain functions on *sugars* and only after one day or two of real fasting the metabolism can switch to using ketons derived from (more compactly stored) fats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective this is a very interesting question, mostly because it is difficult to completely abstain from carbohydrate intake on a normal diet. Even the popular low carb diets of the late 1990s and early 2000s (e.g. [Atkins Diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkins_diet), [South Beach Diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Beach_Diet)) were just that, they were **Low Carb, Not No Carb**.

We know there are **essential dietary nutrients** for humans, like [essential fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_fatty_acid) and [essential amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid). The reason that these **must** be obtained in the diet is because humans do not have the enzymes to synthesize these nutrients *de novo* (aka, "From Scratch").

From a biochemical perspective we know that fatty acids and acetyl-CoA **cannot** be converted back into glucose or other carbohydrate intermediates. This is because of the **irreversible** biochemical reaction catalyzed by [pyruvate dehydrogenase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyruvate_dehydrogenase), which converts pyruvate to acetyl-CoA. Thus, fatty acids (lipids) can be oxidized to acetyl-CoA (for the TCA/Krebs Cycle) but cannot be further converted to glucose within the body.

In terms of protein, however, amino acids are either glucogenic, ketogenic, or both. If amino acids are ketogenic, then this means they can be converted into acetyl-CoA for the Krebs Cycle. If amino acids are glucogenic, then it means that they can be broken down into glucose. The breakdown of amino acids can be used to synthesize glucose or for anapleurotic reactions of the Krebs Cycle.

As stated in the [editorial noted in the comments](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/75/5/951.2.long) of this question (From the American Journal of Clinical Nutrition), there are daily "requirements" for carbohydrates. However, it does not appear that any diseases are unmasked by very low to zero carbohydrate absorption (which is most closely occurs in the Inuit populations whose diet is entirely fat and protein).

So, if you ask the question "*are carbohydrates essential components of a human diet?*" the answer would be *probably not*. However, as mentioned above, carbohydrates are ubiquitous and it is impossible to abstain from all carbohydrate intake.

---

Below is a picture freely available online from this [website](https://amit1b.wordpress.com/the-molecules-of-life/about/amino-acids/) (from Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry, 5th Edition) of the glucogenic and ketogenic amino acids and the metabolic intermediates to which they can be converted. This is how Krebs Cycle intermediates can be generated from amino acids and are not dependent on dietary carbohydrates.

[image: Ketogenic and Glucogenic Amino Acid Pathways]

Comment: Wouldn't ketogenesis on such a scale (for all glucose needed) lead to severe ketoacidosis?

Comment: @YviDe at first thought you might think so... but according to the article from American Journal of Nutrition it sounds like the Inuit populations live virtually as close to zero carbohydrates as you can get. It doesn't sound like they have any 'problems' like ketoacidosis. Prolonged starvation would also be a similar state - check out this great review from George Cahill...(http://www.med.upenn.edu/timm/documents/ReviewArticleTIMM2008-9Lazar-1.pdf)  I would guess that the development of ketone bodies would be gradual enough in a conversion to fats and proteins that the body could buffer it

Comment: Interesting. Is there data on the actual carbohydrate content of the Inuit diet? Meat does contain *some* carbohydrates, e.g. muscle and liver tissue contains appreciable amounts of glycogen, and all animal cells are thought to have a few % carbohydrate content in the form of ribose, glycoproteins, etc.

Comment: @Roland I don't think there is specific data on Inuit... but that American Journal of Nutrition article referenced above in the comments to the question is kinda interesting - I agree with you, though, some carbohydrates are everywhere

Comment: For completeness, it should be noted that the irreversibility of the pyruvate→acetyl-CoA reaction does not, _in and of itself_, preclude the conversion of fatty acids and acetyl-CoA into carbohydrates; plants do just that by short-circuiting the Krebs cycle into the [glyoxylate cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyoxylate_cycle) and releasing the extra two carbons as glyoxylate (which can then combine with acetyl-CoA to form malate, which can be turned into oxaloacetate, which can be used for gluconeogenesis) rather than carbon dioxide.  However, as almost all animals lack functional (1/2)

Comment: versions of the two enzymes required for the glyoxylate cycle to proceed, it _is_ true _for most animals_ that fatty acids and acetyl-CoA cannot be converted into carbohydrates.  (2/2)