# Co-dependency between carbohydrates, fats and protein in the mammalian diet?

Tags: metabolism, diet

Following up from the question [Are carbohydrates an essential component of human diet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41236/are-carbohydrates-an-essential-component-of-human-diet) I am interested in knowing more specifically how carbohydrates, fats and proteins are linked in the mammalian diet.

For example, cats and other obligate carnivores eat mostly protein, so I imagine that protein has to be converted first to fat and then to glucose and other carbohydrates that the body needs. Does that mean cats are in a state of ketosis constantly? Do cats have special metabolic tuning to optimize on this metabolic pathway?

Human variations seem to suggest that such tuning exists. For example, (historic) eskimoes when fed carbohydrates tend to be especially likely to suffer from obesity and diabetes. This would suggest that their bodies are tuned to exist on protein and fat. What is this tuning?

Comment: What makes you think that cats consume mainly protein?

Comment: @AlexDeLarge The way that my cats growl at me if I try to take meat away from them.

Comment: But meat [does not mainly consist of protein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat#Nutritional_information). Adult cats have a [26% (dry weight) protein maintenance minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_food#Nutrient_chart).

Comment: @AlexDeLarge Did you read the web site you just linked? It says a typical steak has 36g of protein and 7g of fat and 0 carbs. If we exclude bones, the typical mouse is made of 85%-95% protein and 15%-5% fat (depending how fat/starving the mouse is). Human athletes have less than 5% body fat, sometimes as little as 2%. All the rest is bone and protein.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you might be right. I actually did not think about that the non-protein parts could mainly have zero nutritional value. ;)

Comment: Or maybe Inuit are just prone to obesity if they overeat like all Asians

Comment: @GrahamChiu First of all, I was referring to all arctic Eskimoes, not just Inuits. Second of all, a lot of Inuits aren't Eskimoes. Third of all, Inuit tribes are located in Canada and Greenland, neither of which is in Asia.

Comment: I should have said Mongoloid